# An error occurs when implementing the Laravel signup function

Tags: php

**register.blade.php**

```
<script>
            $(".btn-submit").on('click', function() {
                var form = $('.myForm');
                var formData = form.serialize();
                var csrfToken = "{{ csrf_token() }}";

                console.log(formData);

                if(formData == '' || formData == null){
                    console.log(formData);
                    alert('Null 입니다.');
                }else{
                    alert('Null이 아닙니다.');
                }

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/register',  
                    type: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken
                    },  
                    data: formData,  
                    //dataType: 'json',  
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response);  
                        console.log("정상");
                        //window.location.href = '/login';
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        console.log(error); 
                        console.log("오류"); 
                    }
                });              
            });   
            
        </script>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'store']);
```

**RegisterController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Admin;
use App\Http\Requests\StorePostRequest;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        return view('auth.register', [
            '1' => 1
        ]);
    }


    public function store(StorePostRequest $request)
    {
        $name = $request->input('name');
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));    

        $admin = Admin::create([
            'name' => $name['name'],
            'email' => $email['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($password['password']),
        ]);

        return redirect("/login");

    }
}
```

**Admin.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Admin extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'admin';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'email',
        'name',
        'password'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password'
    ];


    protected $casts = [
        'created_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

}
```

**StorePostRequest.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StorePostRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule|array|string>
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ];
    }
}
```

I developed it through the MVC pattern, but a 403 (Forbidden) error occurs.

I wrote Controller, Moddel, View, FormRequest code, but please let me know where the syntax is wrong.

I'm new to the Laravel framework, but I don't know how the data is done.

Please tell me how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue might be with your authorization in the `StorePostRequest.php`

You have to modify it to return true, like so:

```php
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Here are some additional steps you can take:

**Check Laravel's Error Logs:** Open your Laravel error log file (storage/logs/laravel.log). If there are any unhandled exceptions or errors happening before your store method is reached, they would be logged here.

**Route List Command:** Run php `artisan route:list` command in your terminal. It will list all registered routes for your application. Check if your /register POST route is there.

**Disable CSRF Middleware Temporarily:** You may want to temporarily comment out the line `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class`, from the $middlewareGroups array in app/Http/Kernel.php file. If your code works after this change, it indicates the issue is with CSRF verification.

Comment: I changed it to true and ran it, but the same error appeared and was not resolved.

Comment: Can you please share your result if you put this line: `Log::debug($request->all());` inside `public function store(StorePostRequest $request)`, to get more insight into what could be going wrong

Comment: thank you I applied and executed the Log::Debug() function code you sent, but the result is not output and it is not resolved.

Comment: Please try to follow the steps I updated into the answer, for debugging purposes